# How to add sencha button to sencha list

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How can I add a [Sencha Touch Button](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Button) to a [Sencha Touch List](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List) with a item template?

I know, I can do something like this:

```
itemTpl: '{quantity} {productName} <input type="button" value="Delete" />',
```

but this button looks so weird and ugly and I want to have the button the same ui as the [Sencha Button](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Button).

Deciding whether, you clicked the row or the button is working with this code:

```
config: {
    control: {
        'list[itemId="listItemId"]': {
            itemtap: 'yourFunction'
        }
    }
},

yourFunction: function(list, index, target, record, evt) {
    var type = evt.event.target.type || '';

    if(type == 'button') {
        console.warn('delete');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use an [Ext.dataview.DataView](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.DataView) with `useComponent: true`. Then you could set the `defaultType` config to your own custom *dataitem*.

Take a look at the 'Component DataView' in the [dataview guide](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/dataview).

Comment: Is there any sample app / code with a label + a button? I see only one with button only.

Comment: image, slider and label: https://github.com/senchalabs/component-dataview-example/blob/master/app/view/KittensListItem.js

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative on facing the same issue as above,i have went ahead and grab the classes of Button Component from DOM, and applied to my button.

```
   <input type="button" value="Add" class="x-button-action x-button"
    style="display: inline;margin: 1.5em;border: #a6a6a6;"/>
```

In here, i have taken UI classes from sencha touch like x-button-action and x-button as well as added custom style inline(not a good idea though).

Hope it helps !!